# Moving from one activity to another activity in android studio

Tags: android

I'm writing an application in android studio IDE which shows the models,brands ,prices and etc of the cars and I want to move from one activity to another one.can I use putExtra?if yes i wonder if anyone would like to tell me how can i use it.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html follow this link to know about the intents and its uses.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass data between activities in easiest way like this.

In the first activity use out extra to send the data

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("YOUR_DATA_KEY", data);
startActivity(intent);
```

Access that intent on next activity like this

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("YOUR_DATA_KEY");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(this,YourActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("key",value);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following

```
Intent intent =new Intent(FirstActivity.this,SecondeActivity.class);
StartActivity(intent);
```